# Can't install Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to add Crashlytics to an app I'm working on, for that I installed the Fabric mac app and followed step by step the process, but whenever I try to run the app **I keep getting the following error** :

#### Error message

```
'-[Digits start]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbd9ae19c50'
```

---

#### Import

Here's how I'm importing Crashlytics in `AppDelegate.m` :

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

The Fabric app keeps asking me to import Crashlytics using :

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Twitter class]]];
```

But I keep getting the following error :

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'Twitter'
```

#### Version numbers

Version numbers for `Crashlytics` & `Fabric` :

```
- Crashlytics (3.4.1):
- Fabric (~> 1.6.0)
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the pods for twitter and digits, too, if you want to use them. They split all the single frameworks up.

Add digits to your pod file:

```
pod 'Digits', '~> 1.14.4'
```

Comment: but I'm not trying to include Digits though ... I'm importing just Crashlytics & Fabric and that's what I'm trying to use.

Comment: Then why do you add Twitter? `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` is enough to only use Crashlytics, no matter what the Fabrics app tells you. Once you include the Twitter class in that statement, you also have to install the Twitter pod (which probably installs the Digits pod, that's why you get the other errors).